# Postgres (OperationalError('SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected\n')

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

**Problem description:**

Resource and computational intensive ETL pipeline job running every minute are failing. We receive a lot of same error message as shown below. (Seems like its failing almost every minute now). We did observe that the new parameter template is based on a generic template and can be optimized. For example work_mem is 4MB and we increased it. Any advise would be appreciated Thanks in advance.

**Steps we have taken to resolve the issue:**

- vacuum analyze
- increased work mem

**Error Message 1:**

(OperationalError('SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected\n')

ETL SQL (upsert, update, create temp table, indexing, sorting, etc) 
....

Exception: connection already closed

**Error Message 2:**

psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

Comment: You probebly got caught by an SSL (or network) timeout.

Comment: Also, check the PostgreSQL server log file.

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem?  "connection already closed" (which doesn't look like a PostgreSQL error, presumably it is from your framework) sounds like you were done with the connection anyway, or tried to close it twice.  As long as the commit got through before it was closed, there might not be a problem.